# Error when running database update: "DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Cannot add field redirect.status: field already exists."

Tags: 7, database, redirection, updating, debugging

I'm getting the following error when attempting to run a database update:

```
Update #7101
Failed: DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Cannot add field redirect.status: 
field already exists. in DatabaseSchema_mysql->addField() 
(line 336 of /var/www/sitename/drupal/web/includes/database/mysql/schema.inc).
```

It looks like the database update it do to some redirects I added. How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are on Redirect 7.x-1.0-rc3 which was released back on 8 July 2015. It has been fixed on https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect/issues/2541304, so just update your Redirect module to 7.x-1.x-dev.

Comment: That solved it. I didn't even think about it, because I had the latest recommended release.